# Pasting state abbreviation on repeated event key values from the same line in df (R language)

Tags: arrays, r, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have this data set in a csv file which is available for download [here](https://ufile.io/mz388). It is a dataset regarding natural disasters in Brazil and some state level indicators.

In the original dataset each row used to be related to one event, but that caused some problems because each valor in the location column was a string that contained affected Brazilian states names separated by commas.

In order to avoid that, I separated those strings, creating new rows. Now each row contains information regarding the impacts of the event (and some state indicators) specifically in 1 state, and that is the one uploaded on the link.

That led to problems regarding the unique event keys, located in the column '`disaster_keys`'. Since there are more than one lines related to some of the events, now some of the `disaster_keys` are not unique anymore.

To solve this issue, I was trying to concatenate the value of the column `code` (which is the state abbreviation for the given location) to the `disaster_key` of the same line.

I figured out it would be something like this:

```
lapply(df$disaster_key, paste, df$code[which()])
```

So, for example, row one original disaster_key is '2000-0466'. I want the new key to be '2000-0466AL'.

But I just can't figure out what condition to put inside the which function in order to reference the same line of the given disaster_key.

EDIT: noTyme asked me to include the output of dput(head(df,10))

```
structure(list(year = c(2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 
2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L), end_year = c(2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 
2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L), code = c("AL", 
"ES", "MG", "MG", "PE", "PE", "RJ", "RS", "RS", "RS"), disaster_type = c("Landslide", 
"Flood", "Flood", "Flood", "Landslide", "Flood", "Flood", "Flood", 
"Flood", "Extreme temperature"), total_affected = c(37612.3757779619, 
92.0022816126891, 17977.7257049815, 523.571643231768, 105387.624222038, 
10000, 14639.2456238999, 5000, 295.706952864433, 0), total_deaths = c(15.7814164103337, 
0.598014830482479, 6.677440976136, 3.40321568100649, 44.2185835896663, 
3, 5.43743408887709, 6, 1.92209519361881, 7), total_damage_000USD = c(19726.7705129171, 
0, 0, 0, 55273.2294870829, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), insured_losses_000USD = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), magnitude_scale = c(NA, "Km2", "Km2", 
"Km2", NA, "Km2", "Km2", "Km2", "Km2", "Ã¸C"), magnitude_value = c(NA, 
578300L, 350000L, 578300L, NA, 3000L, 350000L, 10250L, 578300L, 
-5L), population = c(2897.881, 3194.255, 18178.042, 18178.042, 
8119.689, 8119.689, 14802.363, 10266.739, 10266.739, 10266.739
), unemployment = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), sewerage_system_coverage = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), percentage_of_woman_30_to_54 = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), gdp_cap = c(6.31, 16.47, 13.96, 13.96, 8.11, 
8.11, 21.36, 19.09, 19.09, 19.09), poor_sanitation_deaths_per_100thousand = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), basic_water_access = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), garbage_collection_access = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), sewerage_or_tank_access = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), max_2_per_dorm_percent = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
    location = c("Alagoas", "Espirito Santo", "Minas Gerais", 
    "Minas Gerais", "Pernambuco", "Pernambuco", "Rio de Janeiro", 
    "Rio Grande do Sul", "Rio Grande do Sul", "Rio Grande do Sul"
    ), day = c("30", "17", "01", "17", "30", "16", "01", "12", 
    "17", NA), month = c("07", "12", "01", "12", "07", "09", 
    "01", "10", "12", "07"), end_day = c("17", "26", "06", "26", 
    "17", "18", "06", "15", "26", NA), end_month = c("08", "12", 
    "01", "12", "08", "09", "01", "10", "12", "07"), disaster_name = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), disaster_key = c("2000-0466", "2000-0809", 
    "2000-0019", "2000-0809", "2000-0466", "2000-0590", "2000-0019", 
    "2000-0666", "2000-0809", "2000-0456"), gdp_anual_growth = c(1.9439823983, 
    8.9587315681, 5.1114478946, 5.1114478946, 4.3287522279, 4.3287522279, 
    2.5746961428, 4.3087215203, 4.3087215203, 4.3087215203), 
    GDP_deflator_index = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), gdp = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ipca_index = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Could you please include output of  `dput(head(DF,10))` where `DF` is your dataset for ease of other users

Comment: @noTyme, here it goes! Check out the post again.

Comment: This should work, `DF$disaster_state_key = paste0(DF$disaster_key,DF$code,sep="")`. The search keywords are "R concatenate columns"